# How can i add multiple values to multiple cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, addition, stock

I've made an example in the pictures below of how it should look like.

I would like to add stock to the current stock by using the script.

If we take the images as an example then it would mean that the add stock column needs to add to the current stock column, instead of overwriting it.

Also this needs to happen in a different sheet.

This means that in the example add stock value the cell G5 should be 10 in the current stock sheet.

If any more questions feel free to ask.

[image: Current stock]
[image: Add stock]

Question:

The scrippt that i'm using right now is the following:

```
function V6() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh0 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh0.getRange('G4:I586').getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => { r[2] += r[0]; r[0] = 0; });
  [{in:0,out:7,sht:sh0},{in:2,out:9,sht:sh1}].forEach(e => {
    sh0.getRange(4, e.out, vs.length, 1).setValues(vs.map(r => [r[e.in]]));
  });
}
```

If I run this scrippt all the values from G4:G586 in Sheet0 will add up to I4:I586 in Sheet0

But what I want the scrippt to do is add the value from G4:G586 in Sheet0 to I4:I586 in Sheet 1.

```
    sh0.getRange(4, e.out, vs.length, 1).setValues(vs.map(r => [r[e.in]]));
```

If i change sh0 to sh1 in the row above, then the values won't add up but overwrite it.

Could you help me with the solution to make it add up on a different sheet?

Comment: I got you message and what happened is that I'm just understand what you want and so I deleted my answer so that someone might be more motivated to help you but I guess others are having similar issues with your question.  I turned on my answer again and I'll continue to work with you if you can modify you question and be a little more descriptive of what you desire.

Comment: I've added a question for you so I hope that it is more clear what i want. I'm keeping the question as small as possible so it is easier to understand. Would like to hear from you.

Comment: I gather that it makes sense to you unfortunately I don't understand

Comment: Hi Cooper, could you maybe explain what part you don't understand, maybe we can make it more clear for you that way.

Comment: Well  here's the deal.  We're here to answer scripting questions not questions involve application specific information.  As the question without using application specific information like inventory or stock or whatever because those are meaningless to me .  Instead ask me question that involve scripting issues and terminology.

Comment: I understand what you mean, i've tried to make the question more clear for you by adding the script that i'm playing with now. Hopefully it's more clear for you now, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

#### Calculate and Load the columns that have changed

```
function inboeken() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
  const vs = sh.getRange('G4:I586').getValues();//getting all of the data at one time saves time
  vs.forEach(r => { r[2] += r[0]; r[0] = 0; });
  [{in:0,out:7},{in:2,out:9}].forEach(e => {
    sh.getRange(4, e.out, vs.length, 1).setValues(vs.map(r => [r[e.in]]));//It only loads the two columns that have changed thus eliminating the risk of damaging formulas
  });
}
```

This array maps the indices in the data to columns in the spreadsheet

```
[{in:0,out:7},{in:2,out:9}]
```

- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

#### Additional Question:

> Adding a sheet

```
function inboeken() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sr = 4;
  const sh0 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh0.getRange('G4:I586').getValues();//getting all of the data at one time saves time
  vs.forEach(r => { r[2] += r[0]; r[0] = 0; });
  [{in:0,out:7,sht:sh0},{in:2,out:9,sht:sh0},{in:2,out:9,sht:sh1},].forEach(e => {
    let sh = e.sht;
    sh.getRange(sr, e.out, vs.length, 1).setValues(vs.map(r => [r[e.in]]));//It only loads the two columns that have changed thus eliminating the risk of damaging formulas
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, the code you gave me works perfectly, but i found out i still have 1 more problem that i forgot to mention.
The stock value that is in the I Column needs to be in a different tab. could you maybe help me with this as well?
Would like to hear from you!

Comment: If you thinking about suggesting that the additional sheet is in another spreadsheet then that is possible and I'm going to leave it up to you to figure out.

Comment: Hi cooper, i've tried the new code you sent me but it doesn't seem to work. I changed the names of the sheets to the names that I use so that works but the value that i get in the new sheet isn't adding up it just keeps it at zero. Am i forgetting something to change in the code? would like to hear from you.

Comment: Hi cooper, the edited script still doesn't work like i want it to. Right now it changes the value in the new tab instead of adding it up. Could you maybe look at this?

Comment: Hi Cooper, see my new answer below.

Comment: At this  point I'm in the dark as to what you want.

Comment: And please don't ask a question in an answer just update your question.

Comment: Hi Cooper, Please look at the edited question.

Comment: Please see my new question above.

Comment: I'd love to help you but I fear we are on two different frequencies and I just don't understand what you want me to do.  And as far as your images are concerned all I can say is that they are not worth a thousand words.

Comment: Have you read the part below the images? That is a question about the code what you've asked. Is there something about that, that i can give you more information on?

Comment: Can you share a link to a public spreadsheet where we can actually see what is the code is doing to get a better understanding of what needs to be changed.  Please protect your private information.

Comment: Yes of course:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MI-VUJQds0VCrOM40aR7FnpomeLXFrYl7wLY-qCg9Ew/edit?usp=sharing